# Is clustering a special case of similarity join?

Tags: clustering

Can clustering be treated as a special case of similarity join?

> Clustering [...] organizes data instances into similarity groups,
>   called clusters such that the data instances in the same cluster are
>   similar to each other and data instances in different clusters are
>   very different from each other.

This quote from *Bing Liu, Web Data Minig, Exploring Hyperlinks, Contents,
and Usage Data, Second Edition* describes clustering as a way of grouping similar objects.

Also, **join-around** sounds very similar to clustering to me since it returns all the objects within a specified distance from another object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some algorithms, such an operation can be useful.

In particular, DBSCAN is built exactly in this kind of operation. However:

1. I am not aware of any database that would efficiently implement this. Specialized tools like ELKI drastically outperform databases here.
2. Computing the join may need up to O(n²) memory. These memory requirements may kill you. DBSCAN can be implemented with just O(n) memory.